# Run Query using Linked Servers

Tags: sql

I am trying to disable constraint in a table via the Linked server. I am using the below code and it troughs an error.

```
ALTER TABLE [LINKED_SERVER].[SERVER].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: please write the error as well

Comment: *drum roll* : and the error was?....

Comment: this is  the error message ; The object name 'LINKED_SERVER.SERVER.dbo.' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Comment: seems a very explicit error msg with little room for ambiguity.

Comment: @Thinna, please provide a little bit more context so we can support you and help with the issue. Execution details as well as the entire error message would be useful.

Comment: @G21, Thanks for the comments but I have solved the issue by reversing the linked server from where I need to run the above query, so that I will run the query locally.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE [LINKED_SERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```